# tomcat + spring + quartz = shutdown error

Tags: spring, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

We are trying to do what appears to be a very straightforward thing, but it is not working, and solutions I find online seem to complex for something so basic, so I feel like I should ask again.
We have a Spring web application running under tomcat.  We added Quartz scheduler to it:

```
<bean id="myScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
      <property name="transactionManager" ref="myTransactionManager"/>

      <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>

      <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>

      <property name="jobFactory">
         <bean class="AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory"/>
      </property>

      <!-- NOTE: Must add both the jobDetail and trigger to the scheduler! -->
      <property name="jobDetails">
         <list>
            <ref bean="jobDetailAutoSendPublishedReport" />
         </list>
      </property>
      <property name="triggers">
         <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerAutoSendPublishedReport"/>
         </list>
      </property>

      <property name="quartzProperties">
         <props>
            <!-- Main Scheduler Properties For A Clustered Scheduler -->
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">test</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime">60000</prop>

            <!-- ThreadPool -->
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</prop>

            <!-- Shutdown Hook Plugin -->
            <!--prop key="org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class">org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown">true</prop-->

            <!-- JDBC JobStore -->
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties">false</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">300000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">300000</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

And then when I try to shutdown tomcat I get the following error and tomcat fials to shutdown:

appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 27, 2015 1:09:35 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

My fix is to add the following to web.xml:

```
 <!-- Start Quartz -->
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
         org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
      </listener-class>
   </listener>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>quartz:start-on-load</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value> <!-- let spring handle starting -->
   </context-param>
   <!-- End of Quartz -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [docs](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/ShutdownScheduler) it reads:

> If you are using the org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener to fire up a scheduler in your servlet container, its contextDestroyed() method will shutdown the scheduler when your application is undeployed or the application server shuts down.

Maybe you can add this listener too.